# How to stop Microsoft Cognitive TTS audio playing?

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the JavaScript version of Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk.

The audio is played by the browser when synthesizer.speakTextAsync is called. When the audio is too long I want to stop the audio play but I couldn't find any documentation on how to do that?

Any help is appreciated!

```
    synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, 
        SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromDefaultSpeakerOutput());
    
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
      inputText,
      result => {
        if (result) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(rssesult));
         }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stopping audio playing is supported.

You need to create a `SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination()` object and use it to create audioConfig like this.

```js
var player = new SpeechSDK.SpeakerAudioDestination();
var audioConfig  = SpeechSDK.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
var synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
...
);
```

Then you can call `player.pause()` and `player.resume()` to pause and resume the playback.

You can find more info from the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/speakeraudiodestination?view=azure-node-latest) and [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/8473970eac2a251ff2f9ba02c47688fa27f8a015/samples/js/browser/synthesis.html).

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question.

Comment: That will only pause and resume the audio but it will not stop it technically

Comment: How do you stop it, not pause it. When I click play, I want it to start from the beginning again.

Comment: Classic Azure. Code almost good.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly speak, but you can also make an MP3 as output. After the generation you can play the MP3 file. This makes it easy to pause it, replay it etc. For short text messages the delay is minimal.  Next time you play this sentence, you can play the MP3 directly.  It can also reduce the cost of using the TTS service.  I don’t know the context of you application

In Azure it’s something like

config.SetSpeechSynthesisOutputFormat( SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat....MP3);

Comment: Always nice to have someone put an answer in there that has not been asked but what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the intended way of doing it, but I'm stopping the audio by setting `currentTime` of the internal media element to the media `duration` e.g. fast forwarding the track to the end.

```js
const player = new SpeakerAudioDestination();
const audioConfig  = AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
const synthesizer = new SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
synthesizer.speakTextAsync("text to speak");

player.onAudioEnd = () => {
  console.log("Finished speaking");
};

player.internalAudio.currentTime = player.internalAudio.duration;
```

Answer (score 0):

**How to stop audio playing in azure text-to-speech in js?**

```
let player = null;

const speakText = (textMessage) => {
  const sdk = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
  const speechConfig = sdk.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(
    "",
    "centralindia"
  );
  player = new sdk.SpeakerAudioDestination();
  const audioConfig = sdk.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(player);
  speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-IN-NeerjaNeural";
  const speechSynthesizer = new sdk.SpeechSynthesizer(
    speechConfig,
    audioConfig
  );
  speechSynthesizer.speakTextAsync(textMessage.toString());
};

const muteAudio = () => {
  player.mute();
};

const unmuteAudio = () => {
  player.unmute();
};

export { speakText, muteAudio, unmuteAudio };
```

Comment: I have tried this it's not working