# JS Azure Speech SDK Text to Speech (control volume for AudioConfig)

Tags: javascript, azure, text-to-speech

I'm working with azure text to speech service for enabling voice based outputs. Using [Speech SDK Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=script%2Cwindowsinstall&pivots=programming-language-browserjs).

For outputing the sound, im creating **fromSpeakerOutput** instance with custom iPlayer (as in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/audioconfig?view=azure-node-latest#fromSpeakerOutput_IPlayer_)).

```
const browserSound = new speechsdk.SpeakerAudioDestination();
const audioConfig = speechsdk.AudioConfig.fromSpeakerOutput(browserSound);
var synthesizer = new speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);
```

Issue is, i need some iPlayer customizations like pause, resume, stop current sound. I could see only pause and resume. Is there any way i could cancel current playing sound ?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Microsoft Cognitive TTS audio playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62523344/how-to-stop-microsoft-cognitive-tts-audio-playing)

Comment: I have implemented the same as suggested in the shared link. To be more precise, i want to implement something like volume mute and unmute with js. 

Since its not like audio or video html element, i don’t know how to modify volume of the playing audio.

Comment: Thanks. I have raised an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Issue is, i need some iPlayer customizations like pause, resume, stop current sound. I could see only pause and resume. Is there any way i could cancel current playing sound ?

JavaScript: Added volume getter/setter and mute()/unmute() APIs to SpeakerAudioDestination

```
 public get volume(): number {
        return this.privAudio.volume;
    }

    public set volume(volume: number) {
        this.privAudio.volume = volume;
    }

    public mute(): void {
        this.privAudio.muted = true;
    }

    public unmute(): void {
        this.privAudio.muted = false;
    }
```

Reference: [Speech SDK 1.20.0: January 2022 release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/releasenotes?tabs=speech-sdk#new-features)

Comment: Thanks for adding volume and mute features. Now the SDK is more flexible.